# Store the data from text file to a hashmap

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, storing-data

I am trying to read a text file and store with a hashmap. The file contains information like this:

```
1946-01-12;13:00:00;0.3;G 
1946-01-12;18:00:00;-2.8;G
1946-01-13;07:00:00;-6.2;G 
1946-01-13;13:00:00;-4.7;G
1946-01-13;18:00:00;-4.3;G 
1946-01-14;07:00:00;-1.5;G
1946-01-14;13:00:00;-0.2;G
```

I want to store the dates as keys and then "13:00:00;0.3;G" as value, where 13:00 is time, 0.3 is temperature and G represent a quality code. I wonder if this is even possbile since many rows in the file has the same date? I already wrote a code for storing the data in a list, but now I want to store it in a map instead. My old code looks like this:

```
/**
 * Provides methods to retrieve temperature data from a weather station file.    
 */
public class WeatherDataHandler {

        private List<Weather> weatherData = new ArrayList<>();

        public void loadData(String filePath) throws IOException {
            List<String> fileData = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("filepath"));
            for(String str : fileData) {
                List<String> parsed = parseData(str);
                LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(parsed.get(0));
                LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(parsed.get(1));
                double temperature = Double.parseDouble(parsed.get(2));
                String quality = parsed.get(3);
                
                //new Weather object
                Weather weather = new Weather(date, time, temperature, quality);
                weatherData.add(weather);       
            }
        }

        private List<String> parseData(String s) {
            return Arrays.asList(s.split(";"));
        }
```

I got stuck when implementing the hashmap. I started with some code below, but I do not know how to loop over a sequence of dates. What is the simplest way to store the data from the file in a map?

```
public class WeatherDataHandler {
            public void loadData(String filePath) throws IOException {
                Map<LocalDate, String> map =new HashMap<LocalDate, String>();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filepath"));
            String line="";
            int i=0;
            while (line != null) {
                line = br.readLine();
                map.put(i,line);
                i++;
            }
                String date="";
                String time="";
                String temperature="";
                String quality="";
                for(int j=0;j<map.size();j++){
                    if(!(map.get(j)== null)){
                        String[] getData=map.get(j).toString().split("\\,");
                        date = getData[0];
                        time = getData[1];
                        temperature = getData[2];
                        quality = getData[3];
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: As you said using the dates as key won't work because there'd be duplicates. However if you don't mind the change in semantics you could consider date and time in unity (and possibly convert it to a Date Object) which then gets used as key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) you can create a map where the key is the date and the [map] value is a list.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class WeatherDataHandler {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("filepath");
        try {
            Map<String, List<String>> map =  Files.lines(path)
                                                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(line -> line.split(";", 2)[0]));
            map.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .forEach(entry -> System.out.printf("%s = %s%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }
        catch (IOException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Method `lines()` in class `java.nio.file.Files` creates a stream where each stream element is a single line of the file being read.
Method `split()` splits the line into a two element array (because of the second argument which is the number 2).
The first array element, i.e. the date, becomes the [map] key and the rest of the line becomes the [map] value.
Whenever a duplicate key is encountered, the value is appended to the existing value creating a list. Hence the type parameters for the map are `String` for the [map] key and `List<String>` for the [map] value.

Running the above code on your sample data yields:

```
1946-01-14 = [1946-01-14;07:00:00;-1.5;G, 1946-01-14;13:00:00;-0.2;G]
1946-01-12 = [1946-01-12;13:00:00;0.3;G , 1946-01-12;18:00:00;-2.8;G]
1946-01-13 = [1946-01-13;07:00:00;-6.2;G , 1946-01-13;13:00:00;-4.7;G, 1946-01-13;18:00:00;-4.3;G ]
```